# Adding TabBar using fragments in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

1. I have a no. of activities in my app.
2. Now i want to add tab bar at bottom using fragments in android studio.but my problem is that when i open new fragment inside
   current tab on button click and then switches to other tab.then when
   i come back to same tab it loads the first fragment and not the one
   at which i switched to other tab.
3. Is there any solution for this.

   4.I have tried transaction and [fragment manager tutorial](http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2012/09/getting-started-with-simple-fragment.html) for this but could not succeed.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Bottom Tabs in Fragment State Pager Adapter](http://androidfreakstuff.blogspot.in/2015/09/bottom-tabs-with-fragment-state-pager.html)

Comment: When i replace first fragment with new fragment on button click of first fragment.Then it does not replace it.It overlay on it.

Comment: or new fragment is added under first fragment.

Comment: it seems you are doing add fragment transaction. In that case your fragment get appear over the top of the first fragment. Have you tried the tutorial?

Comment: yes,i have tried this.But could not manage fragments in tabs.

Comment: Yes i have tried this.But i could not manage new fragments inside old fragments.And also there should be separate backtrace for each tab.

Comment: In this tutorial,only one fragment is added inside tab.What about when i place a button in first fragment and on click of that i open new fragment under same tab.And on tab change,when we come back to same tab,it should contain new fragment.